# Lista simplemente enlazada en C

Tags: c

Hola he tratado de ejecutar este código pero al hacer me dice que el exe ha dejado de funcionar..no me muestra ningún error de sintaxis, por favor quisiera me indicaran el error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Registro
{
    int valor;
    struct Registro *sig;
}Nodo;

//INICIALIZAR LA LISTA
Nodo *crearLista(Nodo *apuntador)
{
    return apuntador=NULL;
}

Nodo * crearNodo(int numero)
{
    //CREANDO EL NODO
    Nodo *registroNuevo;
    registroNuevo=(Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));

    //SINO SE PUDO RESERVAR MEMORIA PARA EL REGISTRO
    if(!registroNuevo)
    {
       printf("No se pudo crear memoria para el registro\n");
       return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        //SI SE PUDO RESERVAR LA MEMORIA SE INSERTAN LOS DATOS
        registroNuevo->valor=numero;
        registroNuevo->sig=NULL;
    }   
    return registroNuevo;
}


Nodo *insertarEnLista(int numero, Nodo *apuntador)
{
     Nodo *apuntadorAuxiliar ,*registroNuevo;
     registroNuevo=crearNodo(numero);

     //SI SE PUDO CREAR EL NODO QUE SE INSERTE EN LA LISTA
     if(registroNuevo)
     {
          //SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA  
         if(!apuntador)
               apuntador=registroNuevo;
         else
         {
              //SE USA EL APUNTADOR AUXILIAR PARA MOVERSE ENTRE LOS NODOS
              apuntadorAuxiliar=apuntador;
              while(apuntadorAuxiliar->sig)
                apuntadorAuxiliar=apuntadorAuxiliar->sig;
              apuntadorAuxiliar->sig=registroNuevo;
         }

         return apuntador;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void imprimirlista(Nodo * apuntador)
{
    Nodo *apuntadorAuxiliar;
    apuntadorAuxiliar=apuntador;

    while(apuntadorAuxiliar->sig)
    {
        printf("%d-> ",apuntador->valor);
        apuntadorAuxiliar=apuntadorAuxiliar->sig;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}

int main ()
{
     Nodo *apuntador;
     crearLista(apuntador);
     insertarEnLista(9,apuntador);
     imprimirlista(apuntador);

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el main cuando inicializas la lista, nunca guardas el resultado

```
 Nodo *apuntador;
 apuntador = crearLista(apuntador); 
 apuntador = insertarEnLista(9, apuntador);
 imprimirlista(apuntador);
```

Aunque podrías simplificarlo así

```
 Nodo *apuntador;
 apuntador = insertarEnLista(9,NULL);
 imprimirlista(apuntador);
```

Comment: gracias no lo habia visto jaja...